Gazebo and RViz2 on WSL 2 with ROS 2 Humble - No Grid or Axes in display
I am completely new to Linux and ROS2 and facing some issues with Gazebo and RViz2.
Setup:
Operating System Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL 2
ROS Version ROS 2 Humble
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11400H @ 2.70GHz   2.69 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.78 GB usable)
GPU Nvidia RTX 3050 Ti
I got wsl with wsl --install first then used the documentation https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debs.html to get ROS2 Humble. Then I followed the nav2 installation steps here https://docs.nav2.org/getting_started/index.html. When I do ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py headless:=False my RViz2 and Gazebo show up like this:


When I try gazebo --verbose it sometimes shows me the grid and mesh, allows me to add objects, and after I close and start it again, the mesh and grid disappear again and the problem persists. Note that my VM and Hypervisor platform and WSL and turned on the Windows features settings. I've been trying to fix it for the past 4 hours uninstalling and reinstalling, following different YT tutes, solutions in forums but nothing works :( Any help or guidance would be highly highly highly appreciated. Thanks!
